# ACL scope in hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I just wanted to know whether the ACLs applied in hyperledger composer secure access only when data is accessed through composer , or it is applied till fabric level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACL's only secure access to data when accessed through the composer runtime API, it is not applied at the fabric level.

Comment: For security and privacy at a Fabric level,as david_k refers to  - and   the blockchain infrastructure upon which Composer sits - see  'Data Privacy and Access Control' - http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/Fabric-FAQ.html - Composer can't forego the need to have normal, organisational infrastructure-level security and a proper security architecture in place.  Composer is just one piece of the blockchain architecture - it isn't THE architecture, if that makes sense. Another example is (say) someone trying to 'see' the data on the network before being committed to the ledger